# ElasticSearch: Replace a field value

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there anyway to `"replace a field value"` by another one using a more or less straightforward process?

Example:

```
PUT twitter/tweet/{1...n}
{
    "user" : "kimchy"
}
```

I want to replace `user` field of documents where `"user is kimchy"` setting a new value.

I figure out that the most straightforward way to get that is:

1. getting all documents,
2. change them,
3. save them again.

I'm looking forward to knowing if there's another a bit more elegant way.

Example: Update `field = "new value"` on documents where `field is "value"`. Is there anyway to perform this single command on ES?

Comment: ES has an update API, but since everything in lucene is immutable this is exactly what ES will do as well (delete and re-index). The update API i believe depends on your version of es though

Comment: @Thanks @pandaadb. I know that even thought I'm thinking on `"update"` ES is `re-indexing` documents. I've edited the post in order to provide an example of what I'd like to get...